# Insert multiple document with Hibernate OGM 5.3 into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jpa, wildfly

I'm stuck in an issue trying to persist a List of entities into mongoDB using wildfly and OGM 5.3.
The problem seems to be the size of the List because I tried to save only five elements of the List and it works.
Someone knows why hibernate OGM doesn't support long List persistence? Or a solution to change the transaction duration?

Thank U all.

Comment: If you don't provide more details. we cannot help you. How did you map your entities? How are saving the list of entities? What kind of exception is thrown?

Comment: Thank u for your response, Davide. The entries are mapped as List and we have tried to save them iterating and working on a transaction and using native query db.collection.insertMany() but we get an error because mongodb saved the documents but JPA (its transaction) didn't handle the duration of the operation.
Now we have solved because of in every iteration we read from db to get the _id of a related document.